# Setting up a citrix local ISO virtual area

Tags: citrix

I'm setting up a new citrix box and trying to set a 20gb area to hold ISOs for the VMS.

I'm trying to setup a new lvm area to hold it, but i'm getting an

```
mkfs.ext3: invalid blocks count - VG_XenStorage-287d0e7a-5c13-2b08-9ef5-b62ec8dbb33a
```

Heres the steps i've taken:

```
[root@C1380-ds-kc112-SID6294 iso]# pvs
  PV         VG                                                 Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda3  VG_XenStorage-287d0e7a-5c13-2b08-9ef5-b62ec8dbb33a lvm2 a-   923.50G 903.50G

 lvcreate -L 20G -n isoImages VG_XenStorage-287d0e7a-5c13-2b08-9ef5-b62ec8dbb33a

 mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda3 VG_XenStorage-287d0e7a-5c13-2b08-9ef5-b62ec8dbb33a
```

That's when I get the

```
 mkfs.ext3: invalid blocks count - VG_XenStorage-287d0e7a-5c13-2b08-9ef5-b62ec8dbb33a
```

Answer (score 1):

"/dev/sda3 VG_XenStorage-287d0e7a-5c13-2b08-9ef5-b62ec8dbb33a" is not the correct Path. You have to use "/dev/VG_XenStorage-287d0e7a-5c13-2b08-9ef5-b62ec8dbb33a/isoImages".

Please verify this via "lvs", before creating a ext3 filesystem.

Comment: thx... this helped me out.  End of a long day, and didn't catch my erroneous target.